# How to save black's position in this Game?

Tags: engines, learning, online-chess, middlegame

In this game black made some mistakes which leads to the final position.
While analyzing this game the engine is not willing to capture the bishop.

```
[Event ""]
[Site ""]
[Date "2014.07.05"]
[Round "-"]
[White "ahesham"]
[Black "myking64"]
[Result ""]
[WhiteElo "1455"]
[BlackElo "1398"]
[Time "23:33:01"]
[TimeControl "900"]
[FEN "r1q2r2/1pp2pk1/p1n1bNp1/2b1P1Pp/4PQ1P/8/PPP1BP2/2KR3R w KQkq - 0 1"]

1.Bxh5 gxh5 2.Nxh5+ Kg6 3.Ng3 Be7 4.h5+ Kg7 5.Nf5+ Bxf5 6.exf5
```

Without capturing the bishop on the 1st move how can I proceed as black ?
What are possible plans for black after the 6th move to get an advantage?

Comment: One question, is this game still ongoing?

Comment: black lost this match yesterday.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What could be possible plans for black after 6th move to get
>   advantage?

None. **1...gxh5** is a huge mistake, after which Black is definitely losing.

```
   [Date "2014.07.05"]
   [White "ahesham"]
   [Black "myking64"] 
   [WhiteElo "1455"]
   [BlackElo "1398"]
   [FEN "r1q2r2/1pp2pk1/p1n1bNp1/2b1P1Pp/4PQ1P/8/PPP1BP2/2KR3R w - - 0 1"]

   1. Bxh5 gxh5 2. Nxh5+ Kg6 3. Ng3 Be7 4. h5+ Kg7 5. Nf5+ Bxf5 6. exf5 Rd8 (6...
   Rg8 7. f6+ Kh8 8. fxe7 Qe6 9. g6 Rg7 10. Qf6 Qxe7 11. h6 Qxf6 12. hxg7+ Kxg7
   13. exf6+ Kxg6 14. Rh3) 7. f6+ Kg8 8. g6 Qe6 9. Qh6 Bxf6 10. exf6 Qxf6 11.
   Rxd8+ Rxd8 12. Rg1 Nd4 13. Qh7+ Kf8 14. g7+ Ke7 15. Qe4+ Ne6 16. Qb4+ Kd7 17.
   g8=Q Rxg8 18. Rxg8 Qxf2 19. Qd2+ Qxd2+ 20. Kxd2
```

> Without capturing bishop at 1st move how can i proceed as black ?

**1...Bd4** is an excellent move, immediately threatening the pawn on **e5**. The positions that arise after **1...Bd4** are extremely complex. I have attempted to analyze a few with the help of the Houdini 1.5 and Stockfish 4.2 engines. Black is able to hold the position after **1...Bd4** and make a draw.

```
 [Date "2014.07.05"]
 [White "ahesham"]
 [Black "myking64"]
 [WhiteElo "1455"]
 [BlackElo "1398"]
 [FEN "r1q2r2/1pp2pk1/p1n1bNp1/2b1P1Pp/4PQ1P/8/PPP1BP2/2KR3R w - - 0 1"]


 1. Bxh5 Bd4! 2. Be2 (2. Rxd4 Nxd4 3. Bd1 Rh8 4. c3 Nc6 5. h5 Qd8 6. h6+ Kf8 7.
 Bc2 Qe7 8. h7 Rd8 9. Qh4 Qc5 10. Qh6+ Ke7 11. Qg7 Qxe5 12. Ng8+ (12. Kb1 Rxh7
 13. Qxh7 Qxg5 14. Nd5+ Bxd5 15. exd5 Rxd5) 12... Ke8 13. Nf6+ Ke7 14. Ng8+ Ke8
 15. Nf6+ Ke7) 2... Bxe5 3. Qe3 Qb8!! 4. f4 Qa7 5. Qg3 Bd4 6. Kb1 Qb6 7. c3 Bf2 8.
 Qg2 Rfd8 9. h5 Qe3 10. Bf3 Ne7 11. hxg6 Nxg6 12. Rh7+ Kf8 13. f5 Rxd1+ 14. Bxd1
 Bc4 15. Qh1 Rd8 16. fxg6 Bg1 17. g7+ Ke7 18. g8=N+ Kd6 19. b4 Bd3+ 20. Bc2
 Bxc2+ 21. Kxc2 Qe2+ 22. Kb3 Qd1+ 23. Kb2 Qd2+ 24. Kb1 Qd1+ 25. Kb2 Qd2+
```

Comment: +1,nice explanation with variation...But isn't possible to make a draw after 6th move??

Comment: @NullReference, please see my updated post.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe trying to break the pawn structure with something like:

```
[White "ahesham"]
[Black "myking64"]
[FEN "r1q2r2/1pp2pk1/p1n1bNp1/2b1P1Pp/4PQ1P/8/PPP1BP2/2KR3R w KQkq - 0 1"]

1.Bxh5 Bxf2 2. Qxf2 Nxe5
```